# What is advantage of using hash of descriptors?

Tags: directory

There are two sentences which I don't understand in Tor dir-spec ver 3.
(https://gitweb.torproject.org/torspec.git/tree/dir-spec.txt)

1)

> Descriptors are downloaded by the hash of the descriptor, not by the
>   relay's identity key: this prevents directory servers from attacking
>   clients by giving them descriptors nobody else uses.

2)

> Descriptors were indexed by their digests, in order to prevent malicious caches >from giving different version of a server descriptor

I think the advantage of using hash instead of using identity key directly is to store more descriptors and to search fast in consensus document using hash indexing.

So, I don't understand why using hash prevent attackers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hash and Digest in those sentences are the same thing: you're noting/referring-to/counting/distinguishing descriptors by their has, as a primary key/id. So - that disarms the potential forgery attack with serving old version of the descriptor: an old and new versions are having *different* hash/checksum, so they will be referenced "by difficult ids", so attacker won't be able to give you an old version by request of a new one. Also keep in mind, that hashes like md5 and sha1 and sha256 are usually hardware-accelerated by most CPU's and MCU's, so using them as an ID is a very good choice: it's fast, unique and have a fixed size(by definition of the hash itself).

Comment: So, I think it is possible for attacker to give not an old version but malicious & new version. Is there any mechanism to check integrity of consensus document? I think it is possible to forge some information not related to authorities' signing part on consensus document.

Comment: @장석인 nope, the hash is taken from *all the descriptor data*, so malicious descriptor will have some different contents - and *just* will have different hash. That's why the hashes were selected. You can even speculate that you've forged some data and injected a malicious descriptor - but you won't be able to force the forged descriptor to have the same hash as an original one

Comment: The meaning what you said is that there is hash value of all descriptors on consensus in somewhere, and client compare the old consensus with new consensus whenever client received consensus document. Can I get some links about how this works more detail? I understood client just compare not all descriptors but the most recent descriptor using hash index on consensus previously. Am I wrong?

Comment: @장석인 I recommend to start [here](https://stem.torproject.org/api/descriptor/hidden_service_descriptor.html) and follow the links deeper

Comment: Hmmm... what I want to say is that if I control directory cache, I can inject completely new descriptor of relay which I already controlled on consensus. According to [dir-spec.txt](https://gitweb.torproject.org/torspec.git/tree/dir-spec.txt), client just download consensus document periodically, and check whether there are missing descriptors on consensus through comparing the most recent descriptors which client had. So, client will learn about that injected descriptor. Nope?

Comment: One more thing you'll confirm in docs: directory cache is a digitally signed replica, and a signatures are on root directory servers only: others are just a mirrors

Comment: Where is the consensus document stored on client or directory mirror(cache)? I am hosting tor as a relay on debian, and set DirPort to act as directory mirror(cache).

If someone connect to "http://my_host_ip:dirPort/tor/status-vote/current/consensus.z", where is that file is existed(path) on my debian machine?

Comment: In memory, as far as I remember: the consensus is one of the data sets that's are not cached on disk in real time. Others are residing in your DataDir, file and directory names are self-explainatory, usually. The cached copy - *but not the latest one* - is at file `%your-data-dir%/cached-consensus`

Comment: If consensus is not stored on disk real time, how is it possible to download consensus through url which is my host machine?

Comment: Through URL it is served via app, from memory, an actual copy

Comment: Thx! client doesn't store consensus that downloaded through http request as file?

Comment: It does, but it is not a real time sync